# Stacking tiff rasters

Tags: raster

I am trying to create a multi-temporal raster from 15 raster layers of forest cover. I first set the working directory, listed the files in the directory and am trying to stack those rasters in chronological order.

```
##Listing raster layers in the working directory
list <- list.files(getwd(), pattern=".tif$", all.files=TRUE)
list

##Creating a multi-temporal raster object
stackName <- timeStack(x=list, pattern=".tif$", orderChrono=TRUE, overwrite=TRUE)
```

I am getting the error as

> Error in row.names<-.data.frame(*tmp*, value = sourcefile) : duplicate row.names' are not allowed
>   In addition: Warning messages:
>   1: In getSceneinfo(x) :
>     Some of the characters provided do not contain recognized Landsat5/7/8 scene ID
>   2: non-unique value when setting 'row.names': ‘Not recognised’

Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
library(bfastSpatial)
s <- timeStack(x=list, orderChrono=TRUE)
```

The `pattern` argument is redundant when x is a list of file names. `overwrite` is meaningless if you do not supply an output file name.

You could also do:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(list)
```

Perhaps after sorting `list`. To help you further, you should show the content of `list`.